# bad URI(is not URI?) When running rails s in ubuntu terminal

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, linux, ubuntu

I've been trying to run rails s on one of my project. I'm a complete beginner on RoR and was just trying to get things started by first trying to run the files and see how the website looks like. However, it seems like I'm stuck at this one problem that I can't really find a solution to. Can anyone help me?

Here is the error:

```
/home/peh/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p451/lib/ruby/2.0.0/uri/common.rb:176:in `split': bad URI(is not URI?):  (URI::InvalidURIError)
from /home/peh/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p451/lib/ruby/2.0.0/uri/common.rb:211:in `parse'
from /home/peh/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p451/lib/ruby/2.0.0/uri/common.rb:747:in `parse'
from /home/peh/Desktop/kairos-singapore-master/config/initializers/redis.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
from /home/peh/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p451/gems/activesupport-4.0.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:222:in `load'
from /home/peh/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p451/gems/activesupport-4.0.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:222:in `block in load'
from /home/peh/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p451/gems/activesupport-4.0.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:213:in `load_dependency'
from /home/peh/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p451/gems/activesupport-4.0.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:222:in `load'
from /home/peh/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p451/gems/railties-4.0.0/lib/rails/engine.rb:609:in `block (2 levels) in <class:Engine>'
from /home/peh/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p451/gems/railties-4.0.0/lib/rails/engine.rb:608:in `each'
from /home/peh/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p451/gems/railties-4.0.0/lib/rails/engine.rb:608:in `block in <class:Engine>'
from /home/peh/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p451/gems/railties-4.0.0/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `instance_exec'
from /home/peh/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p451/gems/railties-4.0.0/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `run'
from /home/peh/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p451/gems/railties-4.0.0/lib/rails/initializable.rb:55:in `block in run_initializers'
from /home/peh/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p451/lib/ruby/2.0.0/tsort.rb:150:in `block in tsort_each'
from /home/peh/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p451/lib/ruby/2.0.0/tsort.rb:183:in `block (2 levels) in each_strongly_connected_component'
from /home/peh/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p451/lib/ruby/2.0.0/tsort.rb:210:in `block (2 levels) in each_strongly_connected_component_from'
from /home/peh/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p451/lib/ruby/2.0.0/tsort.rb:219:in `each_strongly_connected_component_from'
from /home/peh/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p451/lib/ruby/2.0.0/tsort.rb:209:in `block in each_strongly_connected_component_from'
from /home/peh/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p451/gems/railties-4.0.0/lib/rails/initializable.rb:44:in `each'
from /home/peh/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p451/gems/railties-4.0.0/lib/rails/initializable.rb:44:in `tsort_each_child'
from /home/peh/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p451/lib/ruby/2.0.0/tsort.rb:203:in `each_strongly_connected_component_from'
from /home/peh/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p451/lib/ruby/2.0.0/tsort.rb:182:in `block in each_strongly_connected_component'
from /home/peh/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p451/lib/ruby/2.0.0/tsort.rb:180:in `each'
from /home/peh/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p451/lib/ruby/2.0.0/tsort.rb:180:in `each_strongly_connected_component'
from /home/peh/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p451/lib/ruby/2.0.0/tsort.rb:148:in `tsort_each'
from /home/peh/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p451/gems/railties-4.0.0/lib/rails/initializable.rb:54:in `run_initializers'
from /home/peh/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p451/gems/railties-4.0.0/lib/rails/application.rb:215:in `initialize!'
from /home/peh/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p451/gems/railties-4.0.0/lib/rails/railtie/configurable.rb:30:in `method_missing'
from /home/peh/Desktop/kairos-singapore-master/config/environment.rb:5:in `<top (required)>'
from /home/peh/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p451/gems/activesupport-4.0.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:228:in `require'
from /home/peh/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p451/gems/activesupport-4.0.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:228:in `block in require'
from /home/peh/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p451/gems/activesupport-4.0.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:213:in `load_dependency'
from /home/peh/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p451/gems/activesupport-4.0.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:228:in `require'
from /home/peh/Desktop/kairos-singapore-master/config.ru:3:in `block in <main>'
from /home/peh/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p451/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/builder.rb:55:in `instance_eval'
from /home/peh/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p451/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/builder.rb:55:in `initialize'
from /home/peh/Desktop/kairos-singapore-master/config.ru:in `new'
from /home/peh/Desktop/kairos-singapore-master/config.ru:in `<main>'
from /home/peh/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p451/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/builder.rb:49:in `eval'
from /home/peh/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p451/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/builder.rb:49:in `new_from_string'
from /home/peh/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p451/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/builder.rb:40:in `parse_file'
from /home/peh/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p451/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/server.rb:277:in `build_app_and_options_from_config'
from /home/peh/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p451/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/server.rb:199:in `app'
from /home/peh/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p451/gems/railties-4.0.0/lib/rails/commands/server.rb:48:in `app'
from /home/peh/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p451/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/server.rb:314:in `wrapped_app'
from /home/peh/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p451/gems/railties-4.0.0/lib/rails/commands/server.rb:75:in `start'
from /home/peh/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p451/gems/railties-4.0.0/lib/rails/commands.rb:78:in `block in <top (required)>'
from /home/peh/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p451/gems/railties-4.0.0/lib/rails/commands.rb:73:in `tap'
from /home/peh/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p451/gems/railties-4.0.0/lib/rails/commands.rb:73:in `<top (required)>'
from bin/rails:4:in `require'
from bin/rails:4:in `<main>'
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have a bad URI on `/home/peh/Desktop/kairos-singapore-master/config/initializers/redis.rb:1`. Ruby can't parse it.

Comment: Thank you for answering! Do you know how I can fix the issue? I'm sorry if the question is dumb or obvious, I'm a beginner at RoR and haven't really got the fundamentals down myself

Comment: uri = URI.parse(ENV['REDISTOGO_URL'])        This is the first line of the code.

Comment: You haven't configured your `ENV['REDISTOGO_URL']` in your environment.

Comment: Do you know how I can do that, I feel that I'm probably asking alot of stupid questions; do you have something that I can read up on myself? Sorry for the trouble.

Comment: you can set value for ENV['REDISTOGO_URL'] in your development.rb if you are in development environment

Comment: Hi dave, I am unsure of what to set for the values. I've read on the redis website to set the value to ENV["REDISTOGO_URL"] = 'redis://username:password@my.host:6789', but this seems to be a default and doesn't work for me. However, setting the value does allow me to run 'rails s' now, except it fails when I try to view the site on localhost:3000

Comment: well you would have to configure that URL with the correct username, password, and host.

Comment: Thanks alot sevenseacat, i guess at this stage it would be best to ask the person who created this project, although the reason why I'm asking here was because of his unavailability. Nonetheless, I will try to get in touch with him and ask him for the correct username,password, and host.

Comment: I should also note that this project actually works for him but not for me. It's funny why only I have this error.

Comment: The project probably requires what's called a dotenv file (.env) or a smiliar file that contains all the special variables that are customizable or contain secret information. Generally, it's good practice not to include the actual file in a project's source control. One way to fix this is for him to provide you with the file that contains the variables you need, so that you can assign the proper values in your instance. If he doesn't want to include the file in source control he could simply add a dummy file that contains all the variables that you'd need so that you can simply edit & rename.